# Why does this query return users not born on the date provided?

Tags: precedence

I am trying to search for a client using name and date of birth. My query is included below.

```
Select * 
From Client
Inner Join Address
On Client.num = Address.cl_num
Where 
   Client.fname LIKE ‘%john%’ and Client.sname LIKE ‘%doe%’
Or
    Client.fname LIKE ‘%doe%’ and Client.sname LIKE ‘%john%’
And Client.year = 1973
And Client.month = 06
And Client.day = 05
```

The results however show clients who weren’t born on that day. Is there a problem with my statement?

The query is run on an iSeries server.

Answer (score 7):

The `OR` clause is short circuiting your selection. `OR` binds lower than `AND`.  Use parenthesis to group that criteria as follows:

```
Select * 
From Client
Inner Join Address
On Client.num = Address.cl_num
Where 
(
Client.fname LIKE ‘%john%’ and Client.sname LIKE ‘%doe%’
Or
Client.fname LIKE ‘%doe%’ and Client.sname LIKE ‘%john%’
)
And Client.year = 1973
And Client.month = 06
And Client.day = 05
```

Precedence rules for operators exist in all languages.  For example, 3 + 5 * 2 will give you 13 and not 16 in most programming languages.   `*` has higher precedence that `+`, the same way `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. If you want the addition, `3+5`, to happen before the multiplication, you'll use parentheses: `(3 + 5) * 2`